# Clone remote S3 carrierwave image to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have two ActiveRecord models both with the same Carrierwave Uploader

```
Template < ActiveRecord:Base 
 mount_uploader :icon_image, ImageUploader
end

Profile < ActiveRecord:Base 
 mount_uploader :icon_image, ImageUploader
end
```

The images are stored remotely on Amazon S3 bucket and when I save the Template.  no problems.

I am creating a new  a Profile object by cloning it from the template.  I would like to also make a clone or copy of the remote icon that was saved with the template and save it remotely too on S3 for the related profile

Note 'I think this should be a copy,  NOT a reference to the original template url

In my controller I clone the object before editing in view and then saving.  I've tried the following which doesn't work

```
profile.remote_icon_image_url = template.icon_image_url
```

I've also tried some variations such as

```
profile.icon_image = template.icon_image
```

can anyone help with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After banging up against this same issue for a few hours, found a workaround, if not a real solution.

The issue seems to be attempting to download the image over HTTPS.  So, our brute force solution is to transmute the target URL into HTTP:

```
new_page.remote_header_image_url = self.header_image.url.gsub(/^https/i, 'http')
```